# Have Pseudo Element Inherit Parents Background Color

Tags: html, css

I have several pseudo elements that are related to varying different parent divs. All these divs have different background colors and I would like to before and after pseudo elements to inherit the background color of the parent div. I also want to do this without using JS and only CSS. I tried setting the background of the before and after elements to inherit, but they just show up transparent.

Comment: but the pseudo element is treated as a child of the container element, so it's background is like the parent by default. see this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L21akpuw/)

Comment: @avrahamcool Not true. Unless you specify `inherit` as the `background` property, the pseudo-element will be transparent: https://jsfiddle.net/0sLaca4u/2/

Comment: unless he's positioning the pseudo element outside the parent element, the BG-color inheritance should have the same effect as the default one. (you created an example with BG-image)

Comment: I am using position absolute on the psuedo elements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `background: inherit` on the pseudo-elements:

```
#mydiv::after {
  background: inherit;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/0sLaca4u/1/)